# How to Resolve, HTTP ERROR: 500 When starting ipython [notebook]

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter

[I am new to Anaconda and wanted to get started with Pandas, But unfortunately, when I want to launch the jupyter [notebook], I get the error shown in the Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAVJz.png)

HTTP ERROR: 500

Internal Server Error
RequestURI=http://localhost:8888/tree

Comment: are you sure you have a notebook server running?  Are you on a corporate machine with pathological proxy issues?

Comment: Please write that (plus how you fixed it) as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the machine was running on a VPN and for some reasons, ipython could not launch on the Virtual Address.I disabled the VPN and notebook loaded on the browser